# Как изменять форму при нажатии на кнопку, но оставаться на этой же странице?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменялась форма и отправлялась(сохранялась(form.save())), но не было подзагрузки страницы и я оставался на этой же странице. Ну если так невозможно, то хотя бы прогружалась эта же страница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант без javascript

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrt_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Прошу обратить внимание на `action` он должен быть пустым или отсутствовать. Тогда отправка формы будет на тот же `url`.

В этом варианте обработчик формы должен располагаться на том url, в той же view.

---

Второй вариант, чуть по сложнее

```
<form action="{% url 'form_send_url' " method="post">
    {% csrt_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

```py
def form_send_url_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
    # Работаете с формой
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        redirect(request.META.get('REFERER')) # или reverse(<название урла с которого отправляли форму>)
    ...
```

В данном варианте, после отправки формы и возврате на страницу при нажатии F5 не будет отправляться еще один запрос. То есть не будет возможности вечно отправлять запросы комбинацией `F5, Enter`

---

Вариант с JS

```
<form ...>
  ...
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   let form = $('form');
   form.submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       
       let data = $(this).serialize(); // Данные формы

       $.ajax({
           method: 'post',
           data: data,
           url: $(this).attr('action'),
           success: function () {...}
       });
   })
});
```

В этом случае не важно где находится вью для обработки формы.

Код скрипта можно расположить как в шаблоне, так и в отдельном js файле (этот вариант лучше).

За более подробной информацией рекомендую обратиться к документации по JS

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое)

Comment: Странно, страница вроде быстро подгружается, но изменения не сохраняются(

Comment: проверьте что код отпрабатывается корректна. в PyCharm есть редим отладки с точками остановвки, а если без - добавьте пару принтов и уйнайте что не так

Comment: Я понял, что не так.. У меня же в функции не было form.save() и проверки на метод POST, щас конечно тоже не работает, т.к. сайт вообще не загружается из-за того, что не видит аргумент в виде id объекта

Comment: Хорошо. Если ответ помог, можете отметить его как верный и тыкнуть стрелку вверх. Удачи с проектом :)

Comment: Хаха.. Спасибо)